# How to keep cpp-mode indenting while I use another mode in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I use a custom mode for a certain type of files just for syntax highlighting. But c-style indentation does not work when I load that mode. I don't want to write the rules for indentation for this mode.

[Here is the link for the mode I'm using](https://github.com/shigeya/omnetpp/blob/master/contrib/emacs/ned-mode.el)

How can I use the Emacs default c-style indentation in this custom mode?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`c-mode` installs its own parser to calculate indentation. Therefore, switching on c-indentation is not as simple as it seems to be (you cannot simply set `indent-line-function` and `indent-region-function`).

You can try the following:

```lisp
(add-hook 'ned-mode-hook (lambda ()
               (c-init-language-vars c-mode)
               (c-basic-common-init 'c-mode "user")))
```

I noticed regular expressions for comments and strings in `ned-font-lock-keywords`. As far as I understand font-lock, this is wrong. Comments and strings are handled by the Parse-Partial-Sexp parser (see `syntax-ppss`) and not via regular expressions.
Furthermore, `ned-mode` should be derived from `prog-mode` and not from `text-mode`.